# use javascript value and doPostback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

i have a page where on click of a button, a javascript function runs. It then aggregates some data and places the data on a hidden field in this page. It then opens a new window. This new window picks up this aggregated data like so :-

```
$('#accepted').val(window.opener.$('#accepted').val());
```

where accepted is the hidden field in both parent and child window (no runat="server" was used). The issue now is that i require this data to databind two grids. Currently I've done a doPostback on both grids, but what i really want to do is doPostback for the form once and handle the databinding the PageLoad event. So two questions :-

1) How do i doPostback the form?

2) How do i do this while still being able to differentiate from the actual form submission?

Answer (score 1):

To post the form you should just be able to add a call to __doPostback in your javascript, after the accepted field is set.  You can use the EventTarget and EventArgument parameters of the __doPostback to control the binding in your grid.

So, you could put this in your js:

```
__doPostback('rebindGrid', '');
```

and then this in your page load event:

```
if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "rebindGrid")
{
    //....Do so stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to tie it in more directly with the postback model I wrap mine with some C#

C# Extension Method

```
public static string GetPostBackLink (this Control c, string argument = "") {
 return c.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(ctl, argument, true) + ";";
}
```

ASPX

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lnkDoThis" runat="server" onclick="lnkDoThis_Click" 
      style="display: none;"></asp:LinkButton>

<asp:HiddenField id="hdnParamHolder" runat="server" />
```

JS

```
function DoSomething(param) { 
 $("[id$='hdnDealTemp']").val(param);
 <%= lnkDoThis.GetPostBackLink() %> 
}
```

CodeBehind

```
protected void lnkDoThis_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) { 
 var myParam = hdnParamHolder.Value;
 // Do server actions here
}
```

As for the opening in a second window ... I am not sure I follow when you want this to happen? If it is after the postback you will need to read from the hdnParamHolder control when the page reloads.